# divide array into smaller arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an first `$array1` of 200 integer values,`$array1` integer values are random values and second array say as below

```
$array2= array('30','40,'70','30','30');
```

Both the arrays are generating dynamically.

I want to divide my `$array1` into smaller arrays as per `$array2` values, as first 30 integers from `$array1` will make separate array, later 40 intergers from `$array1` will make second new array and so on. From above example there will be 5 new arrays.

Can anyone please help me.

I tried below below it can just divide based on values assigned. But it is not useful

```
$arrays = array_chunk($array1, 30);
```

Comment: Loop through array2 and do an array_slice() from your array1 into a new array to get the necessary lengths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate over the array of chunk sizes and cut off an appropriate portion of your input array each time:

```
$input = range(0, 199);
$chunks = array(30, 40, 70, 30, 30);
$output = array();
$processed = 0;

while($chunks) {
    $processed += $size = array_shift($chunks);
    $output[] = array_slice($input, $processed, $size);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for your help, in '$array1' i have randomly generated integers

Comment: Hi Jon, need to use $output[] = array_chunk($input, $processed, $size); Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you try this

```
       $startingPoint = 0;
       foreach($array2 as $val)

       {
       for($i = $startingPoint ; $i < $startingPoint + $val ; $i++)
        { $array1[$i]  }
        $startingPoint += $val
       }
```

Comment: Hi Devesh, thanks!! But not getting required o/p